# retain URL of webserver even after redirecting to app server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I am using a web server (www.domain.com)which route 53 hits and then redirects to app server(www.example.com).
Now I want to retain the web server URL even after redirecting to app server.
If I must write a rewrite rule on httpd. where do I must write? what do I must write? and on which file do I have to write.

Comment: you want to reverse proxy, which is different from redirect.

Comment: Hello ezra-s thank for that and can you please elaborate on thelines that I have to add in the proxy.conf if I am doing on web server